# Form submission working during development but not when I deploy on bluehost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, deployment, vite

The form submits and sends an email to my email that is with bluehost when I test it on my localhost but when I upload the site to bluehost shared hosting, the form submission doesn't send anything to my email.

This is the first site I've built that I am hosting. Any help is appreciated!

Front End form submission handler

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      message: "",
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: async () => {
      try {
        const data = formik.values;

        const res = await fetch("/api/sendEmail", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            firstName: formik.values.firstName,
            lastName: formik.values.lastName,
            email: formik.values.email,
            message: formik.values.message,
          }),
        });
        if (res.ok) {
          console.log(window.location.hostname);
          navigate("/thankyou");
        } else {
          console.log("Error sending form");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("frontend Error", e);
      }
    },
  });
```

server.cjs

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { addEmailToMailchimp } = require("./services/addEmailToMailchimp.cjs");
const { sendContact } = require("./services/nodemailer-contact.cjs");

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://****.com",
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

/* POST ROUTE FOR THE CONTACT FORM TO SEND EMAIL */
app.post("/sendEmail", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, firstName, lastName } = req.body;
  const contactName = firstName + " " + lastName;
  try {
    const toEmail = process.env.VITE_EMAIL_USER;
    const message = req.body.message;
    const subject = `${contactName} - Contact Form Submission`;
    const replyTo = email;
    const html = `<p><b>Name</b>: ${contactName}</p>
                  <p><b>Email</b>: ${email}</p>
                  <p><b>Message</b>: ${message}</p>`;

    await sendContact(subject, message, toEmail, html, replyTo, contactName);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Email Sent!" });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json(e.message);
  }
});
```

nodemailer logic

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const sendContact = async (subject, message, toEmail, html, replyTo, from) => {
  /* CREATE TRANSPORT AND AUTHENTICATE RECEIVING ACCOUNT */
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.VITE_NODEMAILER_HOST,
    port: "465",
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.VITE_EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.VITE_EMAIL_PW,
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });

  /* EMAIL DATA */
  const options = {
    from: from,
    to: toEmail,
    subject: subject,
    text: message,
    html: html,
    replyTo: replyTo,
  };

  /* SEND EMAIL WITH EMAIL DATA*/
    transporter.sendMail(options, function (err, info) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(info);
      }
    });
};
module.exports = { sendContact };
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  assetsInclude: ["**/*.JPG"],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: "src/main.jsx", // This should be your main React entry file
        index: "index.html", // This is your custom HTML template
      },
    },
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://****.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },
  base: "/",
});
```

I've tried changing the target on my vite.config.js file and changing the origin in my corsOptions but I cant seem to get the form to send the data to the email when it's deployed.

Comment: Hi NewCoder96! First things first: do you get any error messages, client side or server side? Check your logs. Sometimes mails from servers gets tagged as junk mail. Check your junk mail. I see Vite environment variables used. Have you remembered to create an `.env` file for your app in production?

Comment: @htor Thanks for your response! On the client side, I added a console log to log out the res.status, which returns a 200 code. My junk and regular mails are empty. I do have a .env file for my app, but How do i check if its in production or not? That might be my problem! I ran vite build, but if i include my .env file into production, how do i hide the data in there? As always, any advice is appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think the promise returned by `sendContact()` will always resolve the way things are set up. Try adding a`return` before to catch errors correctly: `return transporter.sendMail(options)`. Does that change anything?